# How to upgrade exiv2 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

I upgrade to the latest Ubuntu, but it is still using the (very) bugged exiv2 0.25 library. Exiv2 0.26 was released more than a year ago, but is unfortunately not the version used in Ubuntu. It makes Digikam crash when doing Panoramas.

Is there a way to make Ubuntu 18.04 use exiv2 0.26 instead of 0.25 ?
Thanks.